# How to extract child of node in data snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase set up is as such:

```
Parent_node:{
    Type:{
        1476663471800:{ //This is a timestamp = Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0) 
            uid: USERS_UID;
        }
    }
}
```

how would I access the users uid? I have tried the following code, but its not extracting the UID

```
self.databaseRef.child("Parent_node/\(Type)").queryLimitedToLast(5).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

   print(snapshot)
   if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
        for each in userDict{
            let uidExtraced = each
            print(uidExtraced)
            //("1476663471700", [uid: USERS_UID])
```

Comment: you want `USERS_UID`????

Comment: hi! yes i am trying to extract USERS_ID :(

Comment: I'm getting an error: Type '(String, AnyObject)' has no subscript members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all use `snapshot.value?.allValues` to get values and than parse it...

```
  if snapshot.exists() {
     for value in (snapshot.value?.allValues)!{
          print(value) // you get [uid: USERS_UID] here

          // ... parse it to get USERS_UID
          print("user_id -- \(value["uid"])")
      }
  }
```

> With this method, order of child might be different. For ordered nodes, you can use `snapshot.child`