# Retrieving Data From Firebase in JSON - Swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve information from Firebase. I can get the snapshot in JSON but I am having trouble accessing it and saving the values in my app.

This is how the code looks like:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(userFound.userRef!).child("currentGame").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                print(snapshot)

                if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {


                    for each in snapDict {
                        self.theApp.currentGameIDKey = String(each.key)
                        self.currentGame.playerAddressCoordinates?.latitude = each.value["playerLatitude"] as! Double
                        print(self.theApp.playerAddressCoordinates?.latitude)
                        print(self.currentGame.currentGameIDKey)

                    }
                }
            })
```

And this is how it prints in the console:

```
Snap (currentGame) {
    "-KUZBVvbtVhJk9EeQAiL" =     {
        date = "2016-10-20 18:24:08 -0400";
        playerAdress = "47 Calle Tacuba Mexico City DF 06010";
        playerLatitude = "19.4354257";
        playerLongitude = "-99.1365724";
    }; 
}
```

The `currentGameIDKey` gets saved but the `self.currentGame.playerAddressCoordinates` do not.

Comment: return output is not in correct json format

Comment: @cosmos check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078420/how-to-extract-child-of-node-in-data-snapshot/40078667#40078667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have multiple objects in your node "currentGame" and you're looking to extract the player address coordinates and current game id key from all of them, here's how you can do it :

```
self.ref.child("users").child(userFound.userRef!).child("currentGame").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                let enumerator = snapshot.children
                while let listObject = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                    self.theApp.currentGameIDKey = listObject.key
                    let object = listObject.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    self.currentGame.playerAddressCoordinates?.latitude = object["playerLatitude"] as! Double
                    print(self.theApp.playerAddressCoordinates?.latitude)
                    print(self.currentGame.currentGameIDKey)
                }
            }
```

According to your database design, you were not accessing the "playerLatitude" in the correct manner. "playerLatitude" is a child of the child of your snapshot.
I'm guessing you are inserting into "currentGame" using childByAutoId(). Therefore, you need to unwrap it one level further to access it.

Also, if you have to access only one child, you can also use :

```
self.ref.child("users").child(userFound.userRef!).child("currentGame").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    let currentGameSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects[0] as! FIRDataSnapshot
                    self.theApp.currentGameIDKey = currentGameSnapshot.key
                    self.currentGame.playerAddressCoordinates?.latitude = currentGameSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "playerLatitude").value as! Double
                    print(self.theApp.playerAddressCoordinates?.latitude)
                    print(self.currentGame.currentGameIDKey)

            }
```

Hope this helps!