# Get data from Firebase child to a label in Xcode 8 swift 3 ios 10+

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display Firebase data to a label in UICollection view.
[image]

I have seen a lot of tutorials and found similar question on stackoverflow but I am little bit confused about this peace of code. help me to found & correctify the error please

```
     var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let m = snapshot.value.objectForKey("AddedInfo/Product")as?
        self.EmailLabel.text = m
    })
```

Comment: post your firebase structure

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 thankx I have updated my question with stucture

Comment: sorry But when I write "product" it gives error

Comment: you are using `child("AddedInfo")` 2 times .. so remove it from reference like `let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()`

Comment: ok dear but how xcode should know what should I want to retrieve or whom child i want to retrieve?

Comment: Can I retrieve any child or subchild object without mentioning the parent child

Comment: check this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078420/how-to-extract-child-of-node-in-data-snapshot/40078667#40078667

Comment: Sir I updated the code but is that possible?

Comment: not really as I said ... and your code is still wrong..it should be  `var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
ref.child("AddedInfo").observeSingleEvent(`

Comment: Yes sir got it.. i  am trying my best to build success

Answer (score 3):

Don't read your entire database, only to display a single value. Instead read just the value you need:

```
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var productRef = ref.child("AddedInfo/Product")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let m = snapshot.value as? String
    self.EmailLabel.text = m
})
```

Comment: Dear sir, @Frank van Puffelen please answer this question, similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544005/get-data-from-firebase-child-to-a-label-in-xcode-8-swift-3-ios-10